# Flowable: how to pass parameters to listener

Tags: java, flowable

I am pretty new in Flowable, so I have a question. I would like to pass some flags to my listener. The part of bpmn looks like this:

```
<startEvent id="start" flowable:async="true">
        <extensionElements>
            <flowable:executionListener event="start" class="my.dummy.listener.DummyListener" />
        </extensionElements>
    </startEvent>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `ExecutionListener` has the method `void notify(DelegateExecution execution)`. Via `DelegateExecution#getCurrentFlowElement` you can get access to the entire `startEvent` flow element. From there you can get any extension element. This means that in order to pass parameters you need to define your own extension elements and then use that in your listener.